# Using ext-all.js or ext.js for production?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I saw in some ExtJs examples that they are only include `ext.js` in the page and ExtJs resolve all dependencies via XHR request after loading `app.js`, *Lazy load*. But I checked the debugger network and I found that ExtJs made `~250` XHR requests to resolve dependencies.

Making ~250 requests for loading an application doesn't seems a good solution. **I want to know** should I use `ext.js` (Lazy loading) or `ext-all.js` (No more requests) for production version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If there is not any really good reason **NEVER** lazy load on a
>   productive system.

There can be some special cases where this makes sense but that should only be done for rarely used classes and not the whole ExtJS lib.

So the answer is that you should either use `ext-all.js` or let the Sencha CMD Tool build you a `app.js` which contains only required classes.

Comment: So can I know WHY ExtJs uses `ext.js` itself and now `ext-all.js`? Educational purposes?!

Comment: @AfshinMehrabani In which case? They do not use it in their productive systems like the API. They recommend that it should be used while developing cause do not want to package your app each time. That  allow you to add new classes to the file-structure which you can now require. That provide us a very smoth developing process; write & add the class -> require it by another class -> use it. In addition the buildtool can resolve the dependencies so that only that classes are packed that are really needed.

Comment: I think I should use the build tool. Thanks, ExtMan :)

Comment: @AfshinMehrabani You're welcome ;) And yes, you definitive should use that. It was recently released in [v.3.x](http://www.sencha.com/products/sencha-cmd/download) and there were a lot of changes. All in all it's a great tool.